# Power Automate - Project Online - How can I get the Lists/items for a specific Project sharepoint site in Project Online?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, project-online

In project online each created project has it`s own sharepoint site with lista and items. I`m trying to grab those lists/items, but I can`t make it to work.

I`ve tried using the url of the project sharepoint site in a Get Lists actions, but all I get is that it`s not finding that site as a Sharepoint Site.

Comment: More info please, far too hard to help.

Comment: are you sure the project site is SharePoint Online? If the site is on-premises SharePoint, you would need to use an on-premises data gateway to connect it to Power Automate.

Comment: More info please, far too hard to help